# How to return two values ​in an array and sum them separately

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to sum t1[] and t2[] separately. What i need to do in this exercise  is to write a program that takes two 5-digit series of integers from the user and stores them in two arrays. Then the program should calculate the sum of the elements in each array and tell you which of the arrays is larger. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly ;/

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void pobierzliczby1(int t1[]) {
    int liczba1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cout << "Podaj liczbe: ";
        cin >> liczba1;
        t1[i] = liczba1;
    }
    
}
void pobierzliczby2(int t2[]) {
    int liczba2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cout << "Podaj liczbe: ";
        cin >> liczba2;
        t2[i] = liczba2;

}
}
float suma(int t1[], int t2[]){
    float suma1 = 0;
    float suma2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    suma1+= t1[i];
    
    suma2+=t2[i];
        
}
    return tuple(suma1, suma2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int t1[i];
    int t2[i];
    int suma1;
    int suma2;
    pobierzliczby1(t1);
    cout << "Teraz seria druga!" << endl;
    pobierzliczby2(t2);
    cout << "Suma 1 wynosi: " << suma1 << endl;
    cout << "Suma 2 wynosi: " << suma2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You are allocating `int t1[i];` arrays with an uninitialized value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that you can write **one** function and use it on each array **separately**. Like this

```
void pobierzliczby(int t[]) {
    int liczba1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cout << "Podaj liczbe: ";
        cin >> liczba1;
        t[i] = liczba1;
    }
}

float suma(int t[]){
    float suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        suma+= t[i];      
    }
    return suma;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int t1[5];
    int t2[5];
    int suma1;
    int suma2;
    pobierzliczby(t1);
    cout << "Teraz seria druga!" << endl;
    pobierzliczby(t2);
    suma1 = suma(t1);
    suma2 = suma(t2);
    cout << "Suma 1 wynosi: " << suma1 << endl;
    cout << "Suma 2 wynosi: " << suma2 << endl;
}
```

You don't have to write different functions that do the same thing just because the functions are working with different variables. The function can be called with different variables and the parameters in the function get the values of whatever variables were used to call the function.

Some other mistakes in your code. You wrote

```
int t1[i];
int t2[i];
```

but your arrays are suppposed to be size 5, so it should be

```
int t1[5];
int t2[5];
```

The variable `i` in `main` is unused, so it can be deleted.

Your `suma` function is declared as returning a `float`, but all you other variables and arrays are `int`. Probably `suma` should be `int` as well.

Comment: You noticed `int i;
    int t1[i];` etc., did you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I'll mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this without using functions

```cpp
int main(){
    int t1[5], t2[5];
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> t1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> t2[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum1 += t1[i];
        sum2 += t2[i];
    }
    cout << "First sum: " << sum1;
    cout << "Second sum: " << sum2;
}
```